# Is there a way to work around Java Robot resetting mouse speed in windows?

Tags: java, java-native-interface, awtrobot

In particular, I'm trying to work around this bug: [JDK-8041463](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8041463)

I was trying to see what options I had to prevent my program from resetting mouse speed in Windows. Is there a way to muck with the mouse settings manually, to save and reload them myself? I'm guessing I'd have to write some native code to do that, which I'm not very familiar with. Thought about following [these instructions](http://www.atwistedweb.com/java/jni.html) and then rooting around to see what awt_Robot.cpp is doing, unless someone has a better suggestion.

Alternatively, are there other ways to move the mouse that wouldn't hork up my Windows settings?

This bug is exceptionally irritating!

Comment: There are some command line scripts (like [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/)) that you might be able to trigger by having Java run command line commands, but that probably involves installing those third party programs.

Comment: I suspect you will need to resort to using some external program or JNI/JNA setup to ascertain this information and reset...